# How to JOIN two tables correctly?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Somewhere you have patience for takes you somewhere, only now the last problem.

It works for one party, only for the persons who not have any recipies, the peron with recipies can't see it, it only see a blank ó page.

```
$usersi = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = :id');
$usersi->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$usersi->execute();
$usersis = $usersi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: And what doesn’t work about that? Is there an error? Please include it if so, or the contents of your tables, the results you expect, and what you’re actually getting if not.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Can you share that?

Comment: What i said was 'show only recipes' select by id, and now everybody see each others recipes.

Comment: can you show your tables structures and an example of your expected output please?

Comment: So for every user, currently your query should be displaying recepies linked to him/her. If you want for a particular user, put a where clause. I still might not be getting what you really want here

Comment: Do you only want to select recipes for one user? Don’t use a join; it’s just `SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = :user`, then `->execute([':user' => $user_id])`.

Comment: I pick up 2 id's from 2 different tables. I have a profile page where users can see their own recipies. now they see every recipe of everybody.

Comment: And you want the users to just see their own recepies right? Then add the where condition for id = id of the user viewing the page.

Comment: Can't i need to have it on his own like 'INNER JOIN'.

Comment: Inner join is used to link two tables based on a key column(ideally). The result would be all the records in the two tables satisfying the join condition which in this case is that the userId in the recepies table should be present in user table. To filter on a particular user, you need to know the where clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: It need to be a inner join there are no obstacles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a user with id = 1:

```
<?php
$usersi_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = 1');
$usersi_sql->execute();
$usersi = $usersi_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Comment: It doens't work, because he need to see the other table to see if the id is the same.

Comment: @JoshuaHiwatLonden can you show your tables structures and an example of your expected output please? Edit your question

Comment: @JoshuaHiwatLonden in this case post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The solution on my question is:

```
$usersi_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = :id');
$usersi_sql->bindParam(':id', $ma['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$usersi_sql->execute();
$usersi = $usersi_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
if(isset($usersi[0])) {
?>
```

*Here your HTML code*

```
<?php
}
 }else{
?>
```

*Here your HTML else code*

```
<?php } ?>
```

*This in the top of your php file*

```
$ma_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$ma_sql->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ma_sql->execute();
$ma = $ma_sql->fetch();
```

I used this in my top because it also check if the user is logged in or not, but this above is a part of that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all recepies linked to all users -

```
SELECT * FROM recettes INNER JOIN users ON recettes.id_user = users.id LIMIT 20
```

If you want distinct recepies linked to all users -

```
SELECT DISTINCT recettes.* FROM recettes INNER JOIN users ON recettes.id_user = users.id LIMIT 20
```

If you want just for one user -

```
SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = user LIMIT 20
```

Change PHP call to -

```
$usersi_sql->bindParam(':user', $user_id);
$usersi_sql->execute()
```

Comment: Did you pass the userId through PHP?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/joshuox91/domains/recettes.nl/public_html/new/profiel.php on line 409

Comment: `$usersi_sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = :user LIMIT 20');
      $usersi_sql->bindParam(':user', $user_id);
      $usersi_sql->execute()
      $usersi_sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: SELECT * FROM recettes WHERE id_user = :user LIMIT 20. Substitute the userId here and run in database and see. If you get all results, its fine. Else I am blank.